# How can I avoid boxes in web page layouts

Tags: website-design

Have you any good examples where content on a web page doesn't look boxed in everywhere?

**edit** examples of what I want to avoid:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add one or two screenshots to show us what layouts you're thinking of as boxed in?

Comment: this is a design issue, not UX IMHO. Mibbe migrate over to design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use images with transparent/white background. Allow them to overlap with text and headlines (e.g., objects’ shadows should overlap image bounding box, for example). 
Make text flow dynamic, decorate additional information on margins (here is a nice example: http://www.artgorbunov.ru/projects/komandor-2/). Highlight important objects, make them big, subordinate unimportant ones.

For example, this is a simple text-image-text-image page, but it does not look boxed: http://www.artgorbunov.ru/projects/onetwotrip-identity/

There is another one, it uses geometric forms to break boxes of image boundaries:
http://www.chancecar.ru/

Summing up, it would require a big amount of work to make page not look boxed, so it seems not possible to make site theme/template and apply it to all pages. Content becomes important and will hint you about appropriate form.

P.S. Also take a look at this demo :)
http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/11/hovering-gallery-css3-jquery/demo.php

Comment: Thanks a lot for the examples, they do give a few ideas, but as you say, it looks like a lot of work.

Answer (score 3):

Tilt your grid.
http://marielaurent.fr/

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 options: Lines or big space between sections. BTW you should talk about your problem a little more, because could it be you need another kind of solution.

Greetings!